# The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1. ISSUE WITH ROOM

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I have a problem with ROOM. When i add it and sync project everything is working correctly but if i run and build app i get this error:

The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.

It's my build.gradle code.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}


dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0'

    def room_version = "2.5.1"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

}
```

Comment: You haven't got the Room ktx dependency `implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.1', try after adding that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update Android Studio to Flamingo and set gradle to 8.0.0 and it start working for me.